# Why Retry Policy is not working for spring integration splitter?

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-retry

Retry policy is not working

```
<task:executor id="ticketSourceExc" pool-size="1"
        queue-capacity="0" rejection-policy="CALLER_RUNS" />
    <task:executor id="regulatoryExc" pool-size="1"
        queue-capacity="5" rejection-policy="CALLER_RUNS" />
   <int:service-activator input-channel="ticketCacheChannel"
        output-channel="sourceTicketsSplitter" ref="ticketSerActivator"
        method="fetchDataFromDB">
        <int:poller fixed-rate="10" task-executor="ticketSourceExc" />
    </int:service-activator>

    <!-- I am getting List<Tickets> -->
    <int:splitter input-channel="sourceTicketsSplitter"
        output-channel="sourceTicketChannel">
        <int:request-handler-advice-chain>
            <ref bean="retrier" />
        </int:request-handler-advice-chain>
        <int:poller fixed-rate="10" />
    </int:splitter>

    <int:handler-retry-advice id="retrier" max-attempts="4" recovery-channel="myErrorChannel" >
     <int:exponential-back-off initial="1000" multiplier="5" maximum="6000"/>
    </int:handler-retry-advice>

    <int:bridge id="regulatoryBrigde" input-channel="sourceTicketChannel"
        output-channel="regulatoryChannel">
        <int:poller fixed-rate="10" task-executor="regulatoryExc" />
    </int:bridge>

    <int:chain id="regulatoryChainFlow" input-channel="regulatoryChannel">
        <int:service-activator ref="regulatoryTaskActivator1"
            method="process" />
        <int:service-activator ref="regulatoryTaskActivator2"
            method="process" />
        <int:service-activator ref="regulatoryTaskActivator3"
            method="process" />
    </int:chain>
```

*I have configure retry policy for a Splitter. The output channel is a queue channel with depth 1(for testing purpose). My expectation is when I am getting a list with 10 items ,it should go to exception channel after the queue is full.It is not happening that way.I have put thread sleep in regulatoryTaskActivator1 to block the queue*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That’s correct because sending to the output channel is not included into the advice. This one is only for the *request* part. Please, read docs on matter carefully: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.8.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#message-handler-advice-chain. The advice is applied only for the `handleRequestMessage()` method.

**UPDATE**

For the use-case when you would like to handle limited size of the queue and do some error handling with retrying I would recommend you to output a splitting results to the `service-activator` around a `@MessagingGateway` with an appropriate `error-channel` and possible `@Retryable` on the `@Gateway` method:

```
<splitter input-channel="sourceTicketsSplitter"
    output-channel="gatewayInputChannel">
       <poller fixed-rate="10" />
</splitter>

<service-activator input-channel="gatewayInputChannel" ref="gateway">
   <request-handler-advice-chain>
        <ref bean="retrier" />
    </request-handler-advice-chain>  
</service-activator>

<gateway id="gateway" default-request-channel="sourceTicketChannel"/>
```

If your flow is *one-way* and you don't expect any replies from the `regulatoryChainFlow`, then a default `RequestReplyExchanger` doesn't fit your requirements and you need to introduce a simple interface for the gateway with the `void` method and configure that `<gateway>` for this as a `service-interface`.

**UPDATE**

What I forgot to mention for you that there is need to be used a `timeout` for sending to the limited queue. If there is no such a time out, the sender just seats and wait for the room, which appears there after those mentioned `Thread.sleep(10000);`.

So, what you need is like this:

```
<int:gateway id="stateGateWay" default-request-channel="stateChannel" 
    default-request-timeout="100"
    service-interface="com.biswo.myspringapp.gateway.StateGateWay" />
```

Pay attention to the:

```
 <xsd:attribute name="default-request-timeout" type="xsd:string">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>
                        <![CDATA[
                Provides the amount of time dispatcher would wait to send a message.
                This timeout would only apply if there is a potential to block in the send call.
                For example if this gateway is hooked up to a Queue channel. 
                Value is specified in milliseconds; it can be a simple long value or a SpEL
                expression; array variable #args is available.
                        ]]>
                </xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:attribute>
```

After this I started to see reties in the logs and then `Dispatcher has no subscribers`:

```
2018-10-09 14:53:03.466 TRACE 15808 --- [ask-scheduler-3] o.s.retry.support.RetryTemplate          : RetryContext retrieved: [RetryContext: count=0, lastException=null, exhausted=false]
2018-10-09 14:53:03.466 DEBUG 15808 --- [ask-scheduler-3] o.s.retry.support.RetryTemplate          : Retry: count=0
2018-10-09 14:53:03.568 DEBUG 15808 --- [ask-scheduler-3] o.s.r.backoff.ExponentialBackOffPolicy   : Sleeping for 100
2018-10-09 14:53:03.669 DEBUG 15808 --- [ask-scheduler-3] o.s.retry.support.RetryTemplate          : Checking for rethrow: count=1
2018-10-09 14:53:03.669 DEBUG 15808 --- [ask-scheduler-3] o.s.retry.support.RetryTemplate          : Retry: count=1
2018-10-09 14:53:03.771 DEBUG 15808 --- [ask-scheduler-3] o.s.r.backoff.ExponentialBackOffPolicy   : Sleeping for 500
2018-10-09 14:53:04.271 DEBUG 15808 --- [ask-scheduler-3] o.s.retry.support.RetryTemplate          : Checking for rethrow: count=2
2018-10-09 14:53:04.271 DEBUG 15808 --- [ask-scheduler-3] o.s.retry.support.RetryTemplate          : Retry: count=2
2018-10-09 14:53:04.372 DEBUG 15808 --- [ask-scheduler-3] o.s.r.backoff.ExponentialBackOffPolicy   : Sleeping for 600
2018-10-09 14:53:04.973 DEBUG 15808 --- [ask-scheduler-3] o.s.retry.support.RetryTemplate          : Checking for rethrow: count=3
2018-10-09 14:53:04.973 DEBUG 15808 --- [ask-scheduler-3] o.s.retry.support.RetryTemplate          : Retry: count=3
2018-10-09 14:53:05.073 DEBUG 15808 --- [ask-scheduler-3] o.s.retry.support.RetryTemplate          : Checking for rethrow: count=4
2018-10-09 14:53:05.073 DEBUG 15808 --- [ask-scheduler-3] o.s.retry.support.RetryTemplate          : Retry failed last attempt: count=4
2018-10-09 14:53:05.077  WARN 15808 --- [ask-scheduler-3] o.s.i.c.MessagePublishingErrorHandler    : Error message was not delivered.

org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel 'application.errorChannel'.; nested exception is org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers, failedMessage=ErrorMessage [payload=org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel 'application.errorChannel'.; nested exception is org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers, failedMessage=ErrorMessage [payload=org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: Failed to send message to channel 'stateChannel' within timeout: 100, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=State [id=2426, name=Pamanzi, countryId=141], headers={id=710d13df-dfbb-ba95-8d28-4785d1a1e3d3, timestamp=1539111184973}], failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=State [id=2426, name=Pamanzi, countryId=141], headers={COUNTRY_ID=141, sequenceNumber=2, COUNTRY=com.biswo.myspringapp.model.Country@5fd4ea2d, sequenceSize=2, correlationId=ab423aa4-c80e-6af0-33a8-f57337f25352, id=a70d6b11-fc23-edd9-7973-1342c3fab8a6, timestamp=1539111183466}], headers={id=ee0ffd29-8e6a-ab5a-6ffb-1016fa38457e, timestamp=1539111185074}], failedMessage=ErrorMessage [payload=org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: Failed to send message to channel 'stateChannel' within timeout: 100, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=State [id=2426, name=Pamanzi, countryId=141], headers={id=710d13df-dfbb-ba95-8d28-4785d1a1e3d3, timestamp=1539111184973}], failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=State [id=2426, name=Pamanzi, countryId=141], headers={COUNTRY_ID=141, sequenceNumber=2, COUNTRY=com.biswo.myspringapp.model.Country@5fd4ea2d, sequenceSize=2, correlationId=ab423aa4-c80e-6af0-33a8-f57337f25352, id=a70d6b11-fc23-edd9-7973-1342c3fab8a6, timestamp=1539111183466}], headers={id=ee0ffd29-8e6a-ab5a-6ffb-1016fa38457e, timestamp=1539111185074}], headers={id=34d0e6e6-0af8-1078-5dd7-aa6643ba6c8d, timestamp=1539111185075}] for original GenericMessage [payload=[State [id=2425, name=Mayotte, countryId=141], State [id=2426, name=Pamanzi, countryId=141]], headers={COUNTRY_ID=141, id=ab423aa4-c80e-6af0-33a8-f57337f25352, COUNTRY=com.biswo.myspringapp.model.Country@5fd4ea2d, timestamp=1539111183462}]
```

Just because your `errorChannel` is a `DirectChannel` and there is no any consumers for it.

Comment: @Arthem how to handle this usecase then. My requirement is  ,if the regulatoryChannel is full any new message comes to the channel before it put ,it will try 4 retry attempts them it should go to a error channel.

Comment: See an UPDATE in my answer.

Comment: Let me understand you point
1. I should  have a service activator whose input channel is the output channel of splitter.[ ip Channel:-sourceTicketChannel o/p channel:- a new channel with queue capacity ]
2. The new channel is going to input to my bridge.
3. I should introduce a gateway. **Can you please suggest how to pass my _retrier_ bean to this gateway?**
`<int:gateway id="myGateway"
    service-interface="MyGatewayBean">
      <int:method name="getGateWayMethod" request-channel="sourceTicketsSplitter" reply-channel="sourceTicketChannel" >
   </int:method>
    </int:gateway>`

Comment: You can place a retry configuration to this new service activator.

Comment: One doubt @Artem, do I need a gateway then? Or only a service activator is sufficient for the process.

Comment: Well, if you worry about error handling on the queue channel size limitation, then you need gateway. You can try with the `<bridge>`, but I don't think it has a `<request-handler-advice-chain>` sub-element.

Comment: ,bit confused,Can you please guide me? As per my requirement if my channel size is full ,it should go to error channel after retry. If I am going to put my retry logic in new activator ,why I need a gateway then? If my new activator is connected to queue channel,ideally the retry logic should work .

Comment: No, that's not, because retry is applied only for the `handleRequestMessage()` and send to the output channel is not included into the proxy call. That's why I suggest to have a service activator with the retry around a gateway. In this case the call for the gateway is going to happen in that proxied `handleRequestMessage()`. That's the main point in my answer: you are missing the fact that send output is not included into the AOP interceptor. See docs I pointed in the answer.

Comment: I understood Aretem, with output channel retry is not possible.**That's why I suggest to have a service activator with the retry around a gateway.** Can you please suggest with XML configuration how to config this(I am not able to grab this part)?

Comment: See an EDIT in my answer.

Comment: No, you replace a `requestChannel` with your `sourceTicketChannel`. The gateway sends to the channel and waits for reply from the `replyChannel` header. Essentially you need to send to that queue channel, so, that is what you need for requests in the gateway.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181172/discussion-between-biswomohan-pattanaik-and-artem-bilan).

Comment: Sorry, I don't chat here on SO. It's not so convenient. You can jump to the https://gitter.im/spring-projects/spring-integration to continue the story.

Comment: No me too.By mistake I click on a link.

Comment: I am still unable to link this service activator and gateway in my flow.S Can you please suggest in the code part .How to link these two(activator and gateway) in between splitter and sourcechannel ? Do I need to write some code for  **waits for reply from the replyChannel header** ?

Comment: I edited my answer to show the flow from splitter to the `sourceTicketChannel` with some comment about `one-way` behavior.

Comment: gatewayInputChannel is a direct channel I am going to configure.
`<int:channel id="gatewayInputChannel"/>
 <int:channel id="sourceTicketChannel">
  <int:queue capacity="10" />
 </int:channel>`

Comment: That's correct. You just distinguish the queue channel from the splitter and provide a hook to catch error during sending to that queue channel.

Comment: ,it didn't worked. I haved added a bean for spiltter. Which takes Message<List<Object>> and return Collection. Put a break point which says size is 10. My sourceTicketChannel capacity is 4. I have cut the flow. sourceTicketChannel is not connected to anything. Ideally when 5 items sends by splitter ,it should retry.But nothing is happening.I can see this message is printed 10 times.DEBUG RetryTemplate - Retry: count=0.

Comment: Would be great if you have some simple project somewhere on GitHub to let us to play with your code. Otherwise it will take some time for us to cook one for you...

Comment: I am also thinking same way.Let me try to upload .

Comment: I have uploaded my prototype code https://github.com/bmpattanaik/myDemoApp/tree/master/mySpringApp

Comment: To block the flow I have put Thread.sleep in the service one activator.

Comment: Well, sorry. Your application is too big and there is no instruction how to reproduce. Please, consider to minimize the code and share with what and how to reproduce and what to expect as a README.

Comment: Added the README file

Comment: Please, see an UPDATE in my answer. My apologies for the delay. Your sample was really useful. Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot @Artem.Thanks again for this line **Your sample was really useful.**